# Efficiently eliminate subset of strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, performance

I have one set of unique strings (thousands) and another much larger set of unique strings (over one million). Strings are more or less the same length in both sets (under 10 characters, it is strings used as ids). I need to eliminate a subset of strings from the smaller set keeping in it only the strings that exist in the larger set. In other words, if such string exists in the larger set, I preserve it in the smaller set, otherwise I need to remove it from the smaller set.
Containers for both sets can be of any kind (C#), or it could be just simple arrays. The problem is: I need to use the most **efficient** (timewise) way to remove strings that do not exist in the larger container from the smaller container.

Comment: So what approaches have you attempted so far? Do you have any code illustrating what you've done?

Comment: You've explained well what you need. Would you also explain what you've tried so far and what improvement you are after?

Comment: With using arrays you aren't going to get past the performance cost of this being `O(N*M)` (*N is the size of the small set, M the size of the large set*). Due to the required iteration. If you want to make this faster consider a change in data structure, if the larger set was a hash table it would make this task `O(N)`.

Comment: whys this getting marked as too broad??

Comment: @KeithNicholas Because this question *is* too broad.

Comment: @KeithNicholas - This is a case of suggesting options from a huge range of choices and time the results. It is broad because of the range of possibilities.

Comment: @Enigmativity  Because the OP didn't really talk about other algorithms I give them the benefit of the doubt and take it to mean "what's an efficient" rather than most efficient.  But even if it was, it may take a lot of research to find out, but the actual answer would be pretty short and sweet and not too broad

Answer (score 3):

Linq is the obvious option, just use

```
var list = smallList.Intersect(bigList).ToList();
```

Also, if you want to see how it's done, perhaps have a look at Jon Skeets blog on implementing Intersect.

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-16-intersect-and-build-fiddling/

Example

```
 var random = new Random();
 var bigList = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000).Select(n => n.ToString());
 var smallList = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000)
       .OrderBy(i => random.Next())
       .Take(1000)
       .Select(i => (i*2).ToString());

 var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
 stopwatch.Start();

 var list = smallList.Intersect(bigList).ToList();

 stopwatch.Stop();

 Console.WriteLine($"{list.Count()} in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
```

[image]